# How to use Postresql Large Object API with Spring's JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc

I need to access a Large Object using postgresql API.  This is done like this:

```
PGConnection pgConn=(PGConnection)c
LargeObjectManager lobj =pgConn.getLargeObjectAPI();
LargeObject obj = lobj.open(imageOid, LargeObjectManager.READ);
InputStram is=obj.getInputStream();
```

I need to run this code from my DAO while using Spring's JdbcTemplate.  How can I get access to the connection I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that DataSource has been configured correctly,

```
PGConnection pgConn = (PGConnection) jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create a new connection that would NOT be managed by the spring transaction infrastructure ?

Comment: Inside transaction, you would use DataSourceUtils.getConnection(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());

Comment: Technically speaking, it is better to use `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().unwrap(PGConnection.class)` rather than `(PGConnection) ...`